# IOS 7 : Adding modal ViewController with transparency : Custom Size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

What I want to do is present a viewController that comes from the bottom and has a custom size.  Whatever I seem to do either looks naff (e.g its animated up, flashes then goes transparent), is fullscreen or blacks out the whole screen.  I have read a few solutions with custom delegates handing the animation but there must be a simple way.  Also a lot of the solutions are for iOS 6 <

```
    HackViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HackViewController"];
   vc.delegate = self;
   vc.modalPresentationStyle= UIModalPresentationCustom;
   vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 400);
   vc.credits = CREDIT_PER_LEVEL * building.buildingLevels;
   vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
             vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   }];
```

Comment: I was trying the same, but what i got is that presenting a view controller hides other view controllers of the navigation controller. So as you present the view controller and it covers the whole screen, all other view controllers beneath it get hide and it loses its transperency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna add viewController (say VC2) as a modal over first viewController(say VC1), then in **VC1**, when you are presenting **VC2**,

```
[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In **VC2** `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255.0 green:211.0/255.0 blue:211.0/255.0 alpha:0.8]];
```

And, in `AppDelegate` under `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[self.window rootViewController] setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
```

You can create other views like `imageView` or `label`, etc in **VC2**

Comment: This gives me interesting results, I present the game modally and so it actually hides the game view and shows me the menu, which to be fair is my issue not your code

Comment: So VC1 (menu) presents VC2(game).  Then VC2 presents VC3 (game options).  Using your method,  The background for VC3 is vc1

Comment: yes,,, but if you don't want to show the VC1 background, make the alpha property 1 to the background color of VC3 `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255.0 green:211.0/255.0 blue:211.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];`

Comment: I want to see VC2 through VC3

Comment: The VC you want transparent, makes its alpha low

Comment: Sorry, VC3 is coming up correctly but instead of seeing VC2 behind it, i am seeing VC1

Comment: Make alpha of VC2 to `1`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support iOS7 and above, you can implement this using a custom modal presentation style (`UIModalPresentationCustom`) and implement the `transitioningDelegate` to return a transitioning controller. In the transitioning controller, you will be called when the presentation is to happen, and you can provide the target frame of the presented view controller. This has a big advantage of using the system presentation model, and the system is aware a controller has been presented.

If you need to support iOS6, you need to add the presented view controller's as a subview, the view controller as a child view controller of the presenting view controller, and manager the view hierarchy yourself. This is less than optimal because of manual view hierarchy control and child/parent view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `presentViewController:`, you can do that with `addSubview:`
Keep doing what you are doing but add view of `vc` to view of presented view controller instead of presenting `vc` with `presentViewController:`

If you do that within an animation block, it would look nice.

Comment: I know you can do it that way but then you need to do all of the addChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:nil etc.  Is there not a way you can do it with presentViewController